# Is it possible to add tcp autotuning to windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, tcp, autotune

I have a network application that needs to send messages at 60 times a second. The messages are usually 300-400 bytes, but can be as large as 1500. The default setting for SO_SNDBUF is too small and limits the number of message that can be sent if the network latency is anything greater then 100ms.

The naive solution is to just bump the SO_SNDBUF size to to something large. However, depending on the latency and the packet size that could be anywhere from 64K to 8MB.

One of Vista's new features is TCP autotuning. Autotuning monitors the tcp connection and dynamically adjust the buffer sizes to allow for optimal communication.

I would like to use auto tuning on our windows xp machine so I don't need to guess what my buffers sizes should be.

Is there a way to install either a microsoft or 3rd party tcp autotuner on windows xp?

Comment: crossposted on ServerFault:  http://serverfault.com/questions/147982/is-it-possible-to-add-tcp-autotuning-to-windows-xp

Comment: seems more appropriate to here than SF (regarding a desktop OS).  it's one of those overlapping areas tho, probably ok on both.